# chirality of conformations of cyclohexane

Tags: stereochemistry

How is the chair form of cyclohexane achiral?
I don't think it has any plane of symmetry. I have tried very much to find the symmetry in it, but I cannot figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

The figure shows the symmetry elements in the chair form of cyclohexane. (From molecule-viewer.com ). The point group is $D_{3d}$.

There is a $3$ and a $6-$fold rotation axis through the centre of the molecule, $3$ two-fold axes between opposite sided and at the mid point of the CC bond, and $3$ (dihedral) mirror planes that bisect the two-fold axes.

[image: chair cyclohexane]